# C language - usage of struct to form Matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I know that object oriented is not welcoming in c language but I still trying to work my way because it is possible as later languages based on c works good with objects

so my question is when I try to write a function outside of main it doesnt give me access and doesnt change values of wanted structs , see code below (I marked every things and included working functions inside the main) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int RandomNum() {
  int generate = rand() / 100000000;
  while (generate >= 9) {
    generate = rand() / 100000000;
  }
  return generate;
}

// Object Definition
typedef struct {
  int a, b;
  int Mat[2][4];
} Matrix2x4;

typedef struct {
  int a, b;
  int Mat[4][5];
} Matrix4x5;

typedef struct {
  int a, b;
  int Mat[4][5];
} Matrix2x5;

void PrintMat2x4(Matrix2x4 a) {
  int row = a.a;
  int col = a.b;
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    printf("{%s", " ");
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      printf("%d ,", a.Mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("}%s\n", " ");
  }
}

void PrintMat4x5(Matrix4x5 a) {
  int row = a.a;
  int col = a.b;
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    printf("{%s", " ");
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      printf("%d ,", a.Mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("}%s\n", " ");
  }
}

void PrintMat2x5(Matrix2x5 a) {
  int row = a.a;
  int col = a.b;
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    printf("{%s", " ");
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      printf("%d ,", a.Mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("}%s\n", " ");
  }
}


// NOT WORKING AS A SEPERATE FUNCTION SO I PUT IT INSIDE THE MAIN

/*static void MatrixMultiplication (Matrix2x4 a , Matrix4x5 b , Matrix2x5 c) {
for (int i = 0; i < a.b; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < b.b; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < a.b; k++){
            c.Mat[i][j] = c.Mat[i][j]+(a.Mat[i][k]*b.Mat[k][j]);}}}
}

void setRandom (Matrix a) {
int row = ((int)(sizeof (a.Mat) / sizeof (a.Mat)[0])) ;
int col = ((int)(sizeof (a.Mat)[0] / sizeof (a.Mat)[0][0])) ;
for (int i = 0; i < row ; i++){
for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
a.Mat[i][j] = RandomNum();}}}*/


void main() {
  printf("%s\n\n", "Start..");

  Matrix2x4 test = {2,4,{0}}; // <----- SIZE IS 2X4
  
  int row = ((int)(sizeof(test.Mat) / sizeof(test.Mat)[0]));
  int col = ((int)(sizeof(test.Mat)[0] / sizeof(test.Mat)[0][0]));
  
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      test.Mat[i][j] = RandomNum();
    }
  } 
  
  Matrix4x5 test2 = {4,5,{0}}; // <----- SIZE IS 4X5
  
  int row2 = ((int)(sizeof(test2.Mat) / sizeof(test2.Mat)[0]));
  int col2 = ((int)(sizeof(test2.Mat)[0] / sizeof(test2.Mat)[0][0])); 
  for (int i = 0; i < row2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
      test2.Mat[i][j] = RandomNum();
    }
  }
  
  Matrix2x5 mult = {2,5,{0}}; // <----- SIZE IS 2X5

  PrintMat2x4(test);
  printf("X\n");
  PrintMat4x5(test2);
  printf("=\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < test.b; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < test2.b; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < test.b; k++) {
        mult.Mat[i][j] = mult.Mat[i][j] + (test.Mat[i][k] * test2.Mat[k][j]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  PrintMat2x5(mult);

  printf("\n\n%s", "End   ---> ");
}
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is fix your bracing and indentation.  Otherwise, your code is essentially impossible to read.

Comment: Its possible that your matrices are being passed by value as structures. You should pass them by address and dereference them inside the functions you have declared e.g. PrintMat2x4(&test) and inside PrintMat2x4 use a->Mat[i][j],

Comment: First: Who says object orientation is not welcomed in c? Second: If your matrix dimensions for each type is fixed, you don't need `a` and `b` members in in your matrix structs. If your matrix dimensions are dynamic, you do need `a` and `b` members (better call them `rows` and `columns`), and you also need accessor functions. There are a lot of examples on the net on how to represent 2d matrixes in c. Third: there is no need to tag a c-problem with java. Java has more in common with lisp and python than c, even if the syntax is more similar to c.

Comment: `Matrix2x4` `Matrix4x5` `Matrix2x5`? So you have exactly same code each time for a different size? It will be boring, can't you go generic? like `MatrixNxN`?

Comment: thanks everybody you helped a lot I now know what to study in order to make it work , the reason I paste same code for MatrixNxN is that it didn't worked for me , we just started to learn c and Im really jumping a head because Im also studying linear algebra 2 , thought I won't need to use pointers but I see there is no other way but to study it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this function to work:

```
static void MatrixMultiplication (Matrix2x4 a , Matrix4x5 b , Matrix2x5 c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.b; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < b.b; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < a.b; k++){
                c.Mat[i][j] = c.Mat[i][j]+(a.Mat[i][k]*b.Mat[k][j]);}}}
}
```

You must pass your structs as pointers:

```
static void MatrixMultiplication (Matrix2x4* a , Matrix4x5* b , Matrix2x5* c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a->b; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < b->b; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < a->b; k++){
                c->Mat[i][j] = c->Mat[i][j]+(a->Mat[i][k]*b->Mat[k][j]);}}}
}
```

Your original function doesn't work outside of main, because C is making a copy of those structs for the function's own use.  Therefore the original structs never get modified.  Changing those parameters to pointers means that the function is working with the original structs.